# Problem in Indexing webform result

Tags: webforms, search

I have created full text search in webforms using Search Api and its working fine earlier but when i added some new records, the new records are not indexed and not able to displayed them on view. I don't know why new records are not indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to re-index the site when new records are being added.
You can do it by visiting *http://your-site-url/admin/config/search/settings* and click "Re-index site".[image: snap]

P.S: This will queue the items for re-indexing. The items will actually be re-indexed when "cron" runs for the next time (manually or scheduled cron job.

Comment: I have done this but it says "0% of the site has been indexed. There are 42 items left to index."

Comment: that is because doing this will queue the content for re-indexing. The actual re-index is done when the "Cron" is run next time. Run cron manually at *yoursite/admin/config/system/cron* and later you'll find that your site is completely indexed and your content begins to appear in the search list :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ...Its works for rest of the content but in webforms its still showing the same old records....:(

Comment: is there any other way to apply full text search for webforms as its not working

Comment: the default search API doesn't give much options to customize. You could try using Apache Solr framework which give good options to customize the indexing. A good tutorial for the same can be found at http://web3us.com/drupal6/how-create-web-site-handbook/apache-solr-drupal/apache-solr-3-drupal-7-turtorial-screen-shots